# I was trying to install sqlite3 interface for ruby in my mac snow leopard 10.6.3. But i got the following error any suggestions?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, sqlite

for this command i got this error "sudo gem install sqlite3-ruby"

```
Building native extensions.  This could take a while...  
ERROR:  Error installing sqlite3-ruby:  
 ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.  

/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/1.8/usr/bin/ruby extconf.rb  
mkmf.rb can't find header files for ruby at /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/  Versions/1.8/usr/lib/ruby/ruby.h  


Gem files will remain installed in /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/sqlite3-ruby-1.3.1 for   inspection.  
Results logged to /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/sqlite3-ruby-1.3.1/ext/sqlite3/gem_make.out  
ruby -v  1.8.7  
rails -v  3.0.1  
gem -v    1.3.7    
sqlite3 --version  3.6.12
```

Answer (score 1):

If you have ports installed try:

```
port install sqlite
```

Or if you are using brew:

```
brew install sqlite
```

Does that fix it?

Comment: "port install sqlite, brew install sqlite"  this command also not working it.

Comment: Do you have something like port installed, can you post the output?

Comment: how to check it can you tell me please

Comment: Just type "sudo port install sqlite" and post the output please.

Comment: i entered "sudo port install sqlite" i got result 
sudo: port: command not found